# How to switch Selenium WebDrivers using Gradle?

Tags: java, selenium, gradle

I am running some Selenium tests on a Java project using Gradle.  I would like to have 2 different Gradle tasks: one to run the tests using the local `WebDriver` and one to run the tests against a `RemoteWebDriver` (which will hit a Selenium Grid server).  Right now I have a `base.properties` flag called `useRemoteDriver` that I can set to true or false to run local or remote tests.

Is there a way I can get a Gradle task to either change this property on execution or is there another way I can accomplish this?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. What is this base.properties file and what reads it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand this right, you want a property which has a default value but you can override when calling gradle in the command line.

I use a similar setup where I declare

env=Dev

In my gradle settings file and have the option of supplying
-Penv=Production
Via the command line to gradle